# How to verify method class in test class

Tags: unit-testing, moq

I have a repository with a method called `ConvertToBusinessEntity` which converts the data from the data source to a business object. This method is supposed to be used by other methods in the repository namely the Get, GetAll, etc.

This method is unit tested. I check if the data is being retrieved correctly from the data source and the values are being put in the entity correct properties.

But now I need to test and create the `GetEntity` method which is supposed to call `ConvertToBusinessEntity`. The logic behind `ConvertToBusiness` is tested. I just need to know how to verify that a method in the class being tested is called (not a dependency).

Does anyone know how to do this or any alternative method?

I thought of an alternative method but I am not sure if it's the best. I could extend the class under test and have a counter increasing each time the method is called.

Another one would be to mock the class itself.

What do you think? Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having `ConvertToBusinessEntity` in repository is not very good idea. Responsibility of repository is working with data store (CRUD). Mapping of data types is responsibility of some mapper class. Otherwise your repository has too many responsibilities. Take a look on what you are trying to test:

> I check if the data is being retrieved correctly from the data source
>   **and** the values are being put in the entity correct properties

You see this *and*? Your test can fail on two completely different reasons. Also you should change repository on two completely different reasons. Best approach here is persisting business entities directly. Modern ORMs allows doing that without polluting business entity with attributes or forcing it inheriting some data-access specific class.

If you really want to have data mapping logic in repository, then make it private (actually only repository should require conversion of business entity to some data-access object) and don't care how this logic is implemented. Let it be part of internal class implementation. You should care only about repository being able to accept or return filled business entities - that's the responsibility of repository. It doesn't matter how mapping is implemented in repository. You should test *what* repository does, instead of *how*. So just check that expected business objects are returned by repository.

Comment: I need further help here :) I understand I could have EF entities being mapped to business entities using AutoMapper or similar and that should happen inside my repository implementation so that business layer don't have to reference data acess project implementation (agree?). But the data source is CMS and, at least the way I see it, I need to perform this mapping manually for each entity. Something like node.GetValue<string>("name"). Should I create an interface IBusinessEntityConverter and have injected in the repository? Let me know if I need to explain further. Thanks!

Comment: Also, I guess I understand what you mean by test *what* instead of *how*. But does that mean I should only do integration tests in the repository?

Comment: @Bomboca technically you can keep all conversion logic in repository, especially if you have AutoMapper or similar. It can be internal part of repository implementation. And it does not mean you should use integration tests, though I rarely unit-test repositories (its hard to mock such things as DbContext and such tests are brittle, they hard to understand and maintain). So if I test repositories, then its usually integration tests, also because repositories should not have complex business logic inside. But if I would unit-test it, then I'd definitely use converter dependency.

Answer (score 1):

> I just need to know how to verify that a method in the class being tested is called (not a dependency).

But do you **really** need to do that? If your `GetEntity` method operates correctly, do you really care *how* it operates? Do you really care if it performs its function by delegating to `ConvertToBusiness`, or by some other means?

I recommend instead that you

1. Think of each method as having a *specification*.
2. That specification describes what the outputs and *publicly* visible manipulations it must make. That do not describe *how* a method performs its function; that is an implementation detail that could change.
3. Your unit tests check only that your methods conform to their specification.
4. You might nevertheless use your knowledge about the implementation to choose good test cases.

---

But, you might declare, if I do that I am not *unit* testing my method code; my test of `GetEntity` depends on both the `GetEntity` method and the `ConvertToBusiness` method: two units, so an integration test rather than a unit test. But do you mock the methods of the runtime environment? Of course not. The line between unit and integration testing is not so clear.

More philosophically, you *can not* create good mock objects in many cases. The reason is that, for most methods, the manner in which an object delegates to associated objects is *undefined*. Whether it does delegate, and how, is left by the specification as an implementation detail. The only requirement is that, on delegating, the method satisfies the preconditions of its delegate. In such a situation, only a *fully functional* (non-mock) delegate will do. If the real object checks its preconditions, failure to satisfy a precondition on delegating will cause a test failure. And debugging that test failure will be easy.

Comment: Thanks for your insights @Raedwald. A little bit more about this case. Actually, the data source is a CMS database so I created a CmsContext. Meaning the repository doesn't match a database table. Doesn't it make sense here to mock the CmsContext and assure that the interaction with it is correct? I am now thinking of having a new dependency IBusinessEntityConverter to accommodate the ConvertToBusinessEntity method and mock it so I can verify it is being used to return the result. Is it all making sense?

Comment: @Bomboca Mocking your database, or the interface through which you access the database, makes sense. Without more detail I can't be precise. Your original question was about mocking individual methods, not whole services. You might want to ask another question, but I first recommend you search SO for questions about unit testing data-base access and service layers.

Comment: That's useful indeed. Thank you! I had to accept our colleague's answer. Sorry I couldn't accept both. Your insight was also very useful and I shall search SO as you suggested.